# Deploying Ruby on Rails to Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, postgresql, heroku

I am trying to upload RoR application to Heroku.

OS - Ubuntu, ruby version - 2.2.2p95, rails version - 4.2.1, database - PostgreSQL, installed RoR via BrightBox (Tutorial from treehouse), using git push heroku master to upload.

On the local server app works fine. When I push it to heroku, it gives out an error:

```
The page you were looking for doesn't exist.
You may have mistyped the address or the page may have moved.
If you are the application owner check the logs for more information.
```

Log files say:

```
/usr/bin/env: ruby2.2: No such file or directory
```

I've tried all the possible variants, I could find on the Internet:

```
rake rails:update:bin

Remove bin from ~/.gitignore (But there is no such file)

heroku config:set PATH=bin:vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.2/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin

Adding this to the GemFile: ruby '2.2.2'

Changed #!/usr/bin/env ruby2.2(.2 (not sure about ".2")) to #!/usr/bin/env ruby (in bin/rake, bin/bundle and bin/rails)

heroku run rails db:migrate
rake rails:update:bin

ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/bin/node
```

To upload to heroku, I've configured git, after that logged in heroku, after that "heroku create", after that "git push heroku master", then "heroku open"

And many others... Any ideas how to solve that problem?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the gem rails12_factor installed and `config.assets.compile = true` ?

Comment: I have installed it, but it didn't change anything. I am not sure about the second line, you wrote. Where can I find it? Thank you for your response.

Comment: And actually it is rails_12factor

Comment: Yes, sorry for the typo. The second line should be in your config/environments/production.rb file.

Comment: I did all you've said, but I am still getting this error... (/usr/bin/env: ruby2.2: No such file or directory)

Comment: I really don't know what is wrong with it... Maybe it has something to do with  the BrightBox?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure you mistyped or something else. but `heroku run rails db:migrate` will not work it should be `heroku run rake db:migrate` . It might be because you don't have root page. Precompile issue etc.

Run `heroku logs -a app_name` to see actual logs.

Comment: Actually, they both doesn't work. What the log file tells, I've wrote above. Thank you for the response.